# How to use ffmpeg to change the h264 properties, yuv, fps, tbr, tbn, and tbc of an mp4 file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, I would like to convert a video file such that its video stream changes like so:

- Current video stream: `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2560x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 256:81], 60 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)`
- Target video stream: `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 2560x1080, 272 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)`

(values that differ: h264 properties, yuv, fps, tbr, tbn, and tbc)

... and its audio stream changes like so:

- Current audio stream: `Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)`
- Target audio stream: `Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)`

(values that differ: aac properties)

How can I do this?

---

#### Detailed version

I would like to be able to concatenate, without re-encoding, `main.mp4`, followed by `outro.mp4`, using the following commands:

```sh
echo "file 'main.mp4'" > concat.txt
echo "file 'outro.mp4'" >> concat.txt
ffmpeg \
  -f concat \
  -safe 0 \
  -i concat.txt \
  -c copy \
  concat.mp4
```

What results is a file which plays till the end of `main.mp4`, and then the video freezes, and I hear the audio of `outro.mp4`. The same video frame then stays on, with no sound, for an extra ~30 minutes (end time shown in VLC).

My assumption is that these files are incompatible with each other in some way that prevents them from being concatenated using `-codec copy` (without re-encoding).

Here is the `ffprobe` output for `main.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'main.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 01:13:00.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 348 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 2560x1080, 272 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Here is the `ffprobe` output for `outro.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'outro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 254 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2560x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 256:81], 60 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
```

How can I convert `outro.mp4`, such that I may concatenate the files without re-encoding?

Note that I am OK with re-encoding the `outro.mp4` on its own,
I simply want to avoid re-encoding during the concatenation step,
and avoid re-encoding `main.mp4`.

---

#### ffmpeg build

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3-2~18.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~18.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-vf "setdar=dar=0,setsar=sar=0"`, `-r 20`, and `-qscale:v 2` to the above command to get the exact intended output.

```sh
ffmpeg \
  -i outro.mp4 \
  -vf "setdar=dar=0,setsar=sar=0" \
  -pix_fmt yuv444p \
  -profile:v high444 \
  -bf 0 \
  -video_track_timescale 10240 \
  -r 20 \
  -qscale:v 2 \
  -ac 1 \
  out.mp4
```

---

Side note: If the video contains audio as well, and using the copy codec, be sure to ensure that those are matching too. For example use `-ar` to set the audio rate.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion command for outro.mp4 is

```
ffmpeg -i outro.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv444p -profile high444 -bf 0 -video_track_timescale 10240 -ac 1 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and the result of `ffprobe` shows `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 2560x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 256:81], 84 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 10240 tbn, 30 tbc (default)`, so it appears that  while the h264 properties and yuv have changed, the fps, tbr, tbn, and tbc have not changed.

Comment: BTW, I added a couple of extra arguments to your command: `ffmpeg   -i outro.mp4   -pix_fmt yuv444p   -profile:v high444   -bf 0   -video_track_timescale 10240   -r 20   -qscale:v 2   -ac 1   outro-fixed.mp4`, and that appeared to correct the differences in fps, tbr, tbn, and tbc: `Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 2560x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 256:81], 84 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)`. Now the last remaining thing is to get rid of `[SAR 4:3 DAR 256:81]` after the resolution.

Comment: Alright, managed to figure it out, needed add yet one more parameter. Here's the full command that worked for me: `ffmpeg   -i outro.mp4   -vf "setdar=dar=0,setsar=sar=0"   -pix_fmt yuv444p   -profile:v high444   -bf 0   -video_track_timescale 10240   -r 20   -qscale:v 2   -ac 1   outro-fixed.mp4`
I'll edit your answer to include the working command, and mark as accepted.

Comment: You do not need fps, tbr or tbc to match for concat. SAR also need not match barring a few players which like to reinit decoders.

Comment: that didn't quite work out for me. When fps/tbr/tc did not match, I got that "frozen frame" plus wrong end time/ duration behaviour as described in the original question. When aspect ratio (SAR/DAR) didn't match, but the others did, the concat did indeed work as far as timeline went, but the aspect ratio was wrong (video appeared squashed) in the second and subsequent sections of the video.

Comment: If your input is variable frame rate and/or audio is longer than the video can appear "stuck".

Comment: When using audio copy codec, ac and ar have no effect.

Comment: I suggest you post a 2nd answer with your changes and leave my answer as it originally was.

Comment: As you wish @Gyan edited and moved --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63547723/194982